# How can I create a Drawer below status bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y6LA.jpg), but always get this:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/772cd9a88e08d592690265145bb740d8.png]

```dart
Scaffold(
  drawer: Drawer(..),
  ..
)
```

How do I create a `Drawer` that is not displayed in the status bar?

Answer (score 33):

For this kind of scenario, Flutter has the [`SafeArea` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html). This widget will make sure that nothing is rendered e.g. beneath the status bar, i.e. a padding is added.

To apply this to your `Drawer`, you can simply *wrap your `Drawer` with a `SafeArea`*:

```dart
Scaffold(
  drawer: SafeArea(
    child: Drawer(..),
  ),
  ..
)
```

[Screenshot of the drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLXMY.png)

You can also specify if you want to remove some of the padding added by `SafeArea` using the optional parameters `top`, `bottom`, `left` & `right`, e.g. `SafeArea(bottom: false, ..)`.

Comment: @ГордеевМихаил Glad to have helped you. If you want to show others that this question has a solution, you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark below the score of the answer (on the left side).

Comment: it change the status bar color into black

Answer (score 6):

Adding the `padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),` to ListView resolves the issue.

Comment: In my case it worked, because listview was adding padding under status bar!